# compress file stream node.js

Tags: node.js, terminal, compression

- The function takes two parameters, an input file and an output file
- The function reads the contents of the input file and streams the contents into a gzip output - stream that compresses the input file contents into the output file
- Use the zlib library in Node.js to create the gzip stream
- The function returns the created output stream stream

here is my attempt:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import zlib from 'zlib';


compressFileStream(inputFile, outputFile) {
      fs.createReadStream(inputFile)
          .pipe(zlib.createGzip())
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(outputFile));
  }
```

I got the error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

any idea or help

Comment: stacktrace? Did you try to exclude `pipe(zlib.createGzip())`?

Comment: I am trying to compress the input file and the output will be in output file

Comment: I know that you're trying to compress. Just try to exclude `.pipe(zlib.createGzip())` and check if the error shows again or not. And we need a stacktrace of the error